# How to select a row from an array based on the highest correlation to a given row?

Tags: google-sheets

For each row of a data array X, I want to find the row (number or index) from a data array Y that shows the highest correlation.

| X Row | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |  | Row index in Y with highest Corr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 10 | 5 | 1 |  | ? |
| X2 | 1 | 5 | 10 |  | ? |

| Y Row | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y1 | 1 | 4 | 10 |
| Y2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| Y3 | 10 | 4 | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |

From that, I would want to obtain the row index in Y with the highest correlation to each row in X

| X Row | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |  | Row index in Y with highest Corr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 10 | 5 | 1 |  | Y3 |
| X2 | 1 | 5 | 10 |  | Y1 |

I tried to apply a combination of Index and SortN to Arrayformula(CORREL(X1,Y1:Y)) but that does not work because it seems that correl will concatenate the rows if one argument consists of an array instead of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `byrow()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  B2:D3, 
  lambda( 
    rowX, 
    lambda( 
      labelY, correlY, 
      single( filter(labelY, correlY = max(correlY)) ) 
    )( 
      A11:A13, 
      byrow( 
        B11:D13, 
        lambda( 
          rowY, 
          correl(rowX, rowY) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

...where the range `A3:D3` holds the X table and the range `A11:D13` holds the Y table.

Comment: thank you!

I probably made a mistake applying your suggestion because I got the following error message 
_FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1, column count: 1. _

Your approach however, made me experiment a bit with LAMBDA and BYROW, and I managed to get my desired output using this formula
`=MATCH(
     max(BYROW(A11:D13,lambda(correl_max, correl(A3:D3,correl_max)))),
     BYROW(A7:E10,lambda(correl_max, correl(A4:E4,correl_max))),
0)`

Comment: The `filter()` function will throw that error if `labelY` (`A11:A13`) and `correlY` (obtained from `B11:D13`) are of different height. They should have the same number of rows. I am not sure if the new `match()` formula you quote always gets the correct result — you may want to test it thoroughly to make sure.